Armijo rule intuition
I am trying to intuitively understand the Armijo rule and its application in gradient descent.
Can I interpret it this way: the negative gradient $ \nabla f(\bar{x}_k) $ gives us information about the direction of the steepest decrease of the function only in the small neighborhood of the point $\bar{x}_k $. Therefore, we need to check the function value at the obtained point $ \bar{x}_k + a \cdot \bar{p}_k $ ($ \bar{p}_k $ here and further is our step at the $ k $-th iteration) and ensure that it has decreased. However, we also want the change in the function to be significant, so we compare the function value at the new point not with the value at the old point, but with the minimum value in its neighborhood, which is in the direction of the negative gradient, as $ f(\bar{x}_k) + \beta \cdot a \cdot \nabla f(\bar{x}_k)^T \cdot \bar{p}_k $ when $ \beta \to 0 $ (we can consider $ \beta $ approaching zero since it is often taken to be very small, for example $ 10^{-4} $).

Ultimately, what's important here is that your gradient descent method converges to a local minimum.  The Armijo conditions are sufficient to ensure this convergence.  You'd do well to look at a proof of convergence to understand how the inequalities enter into the proof.

It would probably make it easier for readers of the question if you stated in formulas what the condition you are wondering about actually looks like.

I would highly suggest you check out section 3.1 of Nodecal & Wright. It has more explanations, visuals, and proofs than any answer here will give you. Here are some comments on your intuition that are important to understand. I will not explain each in detail, but know that these are all discussed in the text I mentioned.

The Armijo condition and related rules apply to any line searching method and hence cover more pathological corner cases than might appear in gradient descent.

Just ensuring that $f$ decreases is not enough. The decrease must be proportional to the directional derivative. Otherwise, you could have iterations plateauing at a value where $\nabla f \neq0$. That is why this condition is also sometimes termed sufficient decrease. It is important that $\beta>0$ for this reason. You can see from reading the proofs (e.g., Thm 3.2 of N&W) that they fail when $\beta=0$. Notice also that some conditions on $p_k$ must be true for the function value to actually decrease along the search direction for some value of $a$. This must be shown for each new method you wish to apply this to.

We generally actually don't want to compare the value of $f(x_k)$ with function values just in a small neighborhood $x_k$. In fact, the Armijo condition is satisfied for arbitrarily small values of $a$. If we took these, our iteration would barely move and could possibly not converge. It is for this reason that an additional assumption called the curvature condition:
$$p_k\cdot\nabla f(x_k+ap_k) \geq \gamma p_k\cdot \nabla f(x_k),~\gamma\in(\beta,1) $$ is necessary. This ensures that we can't take $a$ too small (recall this dot product is often negative by construction). Together with the Armijo condition, this set of rules is known as the Wolfe conditions and both are needed to prove global convergence of line search methods on broad classes of functions.


Nocedal, Jorge; Wright, Stephen J., Numerical optimization, Springer Series in Operations Research. New York, NY: Springer. xx, 636 p. (1999). ZBL0930.65067.
